# MapboxGL Native on iOS: Get MGLPointFeature on tap

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have my own custom subclass of `MGLPointFeature`. I create a source for my instances like so:

```
let myAnnotations: [MySubclassType] = /* code that generates those annotations */
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "some_identifier",
                            features: myAnnotations,
                            options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: 40])
```

I also add a `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` that now displays those annotations.

Everything works as expected. My `MGLMapView` properly shows my annotations. Nice! Check!

So now I'd love to know when a user taps on them. (Note that I cluster my annotations, so adding them separately to the mapView does not work.)

Ok... So now I detect the tap like so:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: tapPoint.x, y: tapPoint.x, width: 0, height: 0).insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -10)
// I inset it so that the user does not have to be thaaaat super accurate
let features = mapView.visibleFeatures(in: rect)
```

So now I get those features below my finger. Also still fine!
BUT.... I'd expect that feature to be of type `MySubclassType` as I added that one to the map. But instead it is of type `MGLPointFeature`. So I guess Mapbox somehow copies my custom PointFeature to a regular one?

So... my question is... how to I get to the instance of the point-feature that I created (where I attached additional information that I'd like to know). I know that I can simply add them to the `attributes` field, but then I'd need to query my data again... Is there no easier way?

Also... If I style my points a bit more, having 2-3 layers for it (background and icon f.e.) I get multiple instances of my `MGLPointFeature`... is this intended to be that way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is like a uitableviewcell where you cast it to your own custom cell to access your attributes?